# How to store DOM element specifier as JS variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, global-variables

I'm just beginning to learn jQuery, basically I want to recreate "click outside element" event. A similar question has been asked here:

[How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

But this doesn't work for multiple elements. I want to have multiple drop-down boxes on my page and I only want one to be visible at a time. If a user clicks outside the box or the same drop-down link, the opened box has to close (and a new one has to open if the user clicks a different drop-down link). I have my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JvCUd/2/

I'm trying to store the jQuery specifier (or id) of the currently opened box in a global variable:

```
jsOpenedWnd = "";
$(document).ready(function()  {
...
});
```

The function that I want to use is this :

```
$.fn.toggleWnd = function() {       
    if ( jsOpenedWnd != this ) {
        $(this).toggle();
        $(jsOpenedWnd).toggle();
        jsOpenedWnd = this;
    }
    else {   
        $(this).toggle();
        jsOpenedWnd = "";
    }
}
```

But it's not working properly. I'm aware that this may be a wrong solution to this problem, but just for the learning purposes I would like to know how to make this work.

EDIT:  Finally worked it out. Turns out the answer was all along in the question that I linked, I had to use 
`event.stopPropagation();`

Here is the updated code (only one window is active at a time):
http://jsfiddle.net/HwE2N/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check those using .is() because `this` is a jQuery wrapper and `jsOpenedWnd` is a selector so you cannot compare them using equality

```
$.fn.toggleWnd = function() {       
    if ( !this.is(jsOpenedWnd)) {
        $(this).toggle();
        $(jsOpenedWnd).toggle();
        jsOpenedWnd = this;
    }
    else {   
        $(this).toggle();
        jsOpenedWnd = "";
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vemcN/)